# localhost redirects to localhostc when installing wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have put my *wordpress* folder inside *htdocs* in *Apache*. When i navigate to localhost/worpress it says:

```
There doesn't seem to be a wp-config.php file. I need this before we can get started.

Need more help? We got it.

You can create a wp-config.php file through a web interface, but this doesn't work for all server setups. The safest way is to manually create the file.

Create a Configuration File
```

When I click Create a Configuration File it redirects me to this page:

**localhostc**/wordpress/wp-admin/setup-config.php

Why it goes from localhost to localhostc? Is there a problem with wordpress directory?

Comment: Is there an htaccess file in that directory? Try deleting it.

Comment: Yes it is but I need it.

Comment: Disable it and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: No it doesen't fix my problem.